# How to extract data from unknown data type returned by BS html parser

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qqhVYhuwQsR2GOkpcTwhLvX5QUBCj5tv7LYqXAzB2UE/edit?usp=sharing

The above document shows the output of BeautifulSoup after html parsing. This is a response from an API with POST request. In the website, it  renders as a table.

Can anyone tell what is the data format and why find() and find_all() not working with it.

```
# Import libs
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

# Reading codes from local CSV file on my computer
dp_code = ("code.csv")

# Form Data for passing to the request body
formdata = {'objid': '14'}

# URL
url = "https://www.somewebsite.com"

# Query
for i in dp_code:
    formdata["objid"] = str(i)
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=formdata, timeout=1500)
    out = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(out,"html.parser")
    json = json.loads(soup.text)
    df = pd.DataFrame(bat["form"])
    df.to_csv(str(i) + ".csv")
```

Comment: It would help if you added more info - the parts of your code where you make the POST request, and what produced the contents of that doc (was it just a `print`?), the url...

Comment: Anyway, from what I could see in the doc, you're getting a json response with a `form` value that has all the unicode escaped; if you just used something like `response = requests.post...` you could try `formHtml = response.json()['form']` before passing to BeautifulSoup `formHtml` or `formHtml.replace('\/','/')` (because it looks like slashes were escaped as well, and they don't need to be)

Comment: I have added the code. But omitted the URL for security reasons

Comment: Did you try `BeautifulSoup(response.json()['form'].replace('\/','/'), "html.parser")` or  `BeautifulSoup(json.loads(response.content)['form'].replace('\/','/'), "html.parser")`  ?

Comment: was `response.content` what you saved in the doc?

Comment: response.content parsed the html parser then with json parser and the first element saved as dataframe, then the dataframe to csv.

Comment: what do `response.content` and `response.json()` return?

Comment: Thank you. I would have sent the original wesite address if there was a personal message option available here. I am a bit affraid of legal consequences of posting it publicly.

Comment: That's alright - as I said, I just wanted to know what the original response looked like. Hope my answer solved your issue and helped you understand the reasons behind it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone tell what is the data format

It looks like either json or stringified json - which you probably realized, since you're using `json.loads`; I don't think parsing with BeautifulSoup *before* parsing json is necessary at all, but I can't be sure without knowing what `response.content` looks like - in fact, if `response.json()` works, even `json.loads` becomes unnecessary.

> ...the output of BeautifulSoup after html parsing...

> ...and why find() and find_all() not working with it.

There's not much point to using `BeautifulSoup` (which is for *html parsing* as you yourself have noted!) unless the input is in a html/lxml/xml format. Otherwise, it tends to be just parsed as document with a single NavigableString (and that's likely what happened here); so then it looks [to bs4] like there's nothing to `find`.

Anyway, I downloaded the document as a txt and then read it and extracted the one value [which is a HTML string] with

```py
docContents = open('Unknow Data Type.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read()
formHtml = json.loads(docContents)['form']
```

(The encoding took a little bit of trial and error to figure out, but I expect that step will be unnecessary for you as you have the raw contents.)

After that, `formHtml` can be parsed like any HTML string with `BeautifulSoup`; since it's just tables, you can even [use `pandas.read_html` directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGYuJ.png), but since  you asked about `find` and `find_all`, I tried this little example:

```py
formSoup = BeautifulSoup(formHtml, 'html.parser')

for t in formSoup.find_all('table'):
    print('+'*100)
    for r in t.find_all('tr'):
        cols = [c.text for c in r.find_all(['td', 'th'])]
        cols = [f'{c[:10].strip():^12}' for c in cols] #just formatting
        print(f'| {" | ".join(cols)} |')
    print('+'*100)
```

It prints the tables as output:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  DISTRICT:   |   KASARGOD   |  LOCAL BODY  |  G14001-Kum  |
|    WARD:     |  001-ANNADU  |  POLLING ST  |  002-G J B   |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  Serial No   |     Name     |  Guardian's  |  New House   |  House Name  |  Gender / A  |  ID Card No  |
|      1       |              |     Adru     |      1       |              |    M / 55    |  KL/01/002/  |
|      2       |              |    Battya    |      1       |              |    F / 41    |  KL/01/002/  |
|      3       |              |              |  MOIDEEN KU  |     289      |  C.H.NAGAR   |    F / 22    |  SECID15757  |
|     566      |              |  MOHAMMED K  |     296      |  ANNADKA HO  |    M / 49    |  SECID15400  |
|     567      |              |  MOIDDEEN K  |     296      |  ANNADKA HO  |    F / 40    |  SECID15400  |
|     568      |              |  MOHAMMED K  |     296      |  MUNDRAKOLA  |    M / 36    |  SECID15400  |
|     569      |              |    RADHA     |     381      |  MACHAVU HO  |    M / 23    |  SECID15400  |
|     570      |              |  SHIVAPPA S  |     576      |  UJJANTHODY  |    F / 47    |  ZII0819813  |
|     571      |              |  SURESHA K   |     826      |  KARUVALTHA  |    F / 33    |  JWQ1718857  |
|  കൂട്ടിച്ചേ  |
|     572      |   DIVYA K    |  SUNDARA K   |     182      |  BHANDARA V  |    F / 24    |  ZII0767137  |
|     573      |   KUNHAMMA   |  ACHU BELCH  |     185      |  PODIPALLA   |    F / 84    |  KL/01/002/  |
|     574      |  SUJATHA M   |  KESHAVAN K  |     186      |  PODIPALLA   |    F / 48    |  JWQ1687797  |
|     575      |   SARATH M   |  SUJATHA M   |     186      |  PODIPALLA   |    M / 25    |  SECID4BCFE  |
|     576      |   SAJITH K   |  SUJATHA M   |     186      |  PODIPPALLA  |    M / 21    |  ZII3300043  |
|  തിരുത്തലുക  |
|     ഇല്ല     |
|  ഒഴിവാക്കലു  |
|     ഇല്ല     |
|  |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: How can make this to pandas dataframe?

Comment: @user3384929 you can get dataframe from `formHtml` directly.  `dfList = pandas.read_html(formHtml)` and then `dfList[0]` will return the first table, and  `dfList[1]` will return the second table